# Бот на node.js и соединение с MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js, бот

Есть бот который следит за обменами на Steam и при появлении предложения должен получить данные из БД(MySql), интервал между обменами разный, может и 2ч. стоять без дела, а может и каждые 5сек получать новые.

Вопрос: **Как правильно держать соединение с MySql?**
Держать его постоянно или подключатся, получать данные и отключатся?
При постоянном подключении сервер через время отключит бота от БД.

**Вариант 1**
Подключатся только при выполнение запроса:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var cfg = require('config');
var connection;

function conn_db(){
    connection = mysql.createConnection(cfg.db);
    connection.on('error', function(e) {
        if(e) console.error('Ошибка БД: '+e.code);
    });
    connection.connect(function(e){
        if(e) console.error('Ошибка подключения к БД: '+e.code);
    });
}

function sql(sql,callback){
    conn_db();
    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
        if(err) console.error('Ошибка выполнения запроса к БД: '+err.code);
        callback(rows);
    });
    connection.end();
}

sql('SELECT * FROM `users`',function(data){
    console.log('Data: ', data);
});
```

Вроде бы всё хорошо, но что произойдёт если во время отправки одного запроса будет ещё один, он создаст ещё одно подключение и дойдёт ли ответ, я не знаю.

**Вариант 2**
Не отключатся от сервера самому, и проверять подключение при выполнение запроса:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var cfg = require('config');
var connection, check_conn = false;

function conn_db(){
    connection = mysql.createConnection(cfg.db);
    connection.on('error', function(e) {
        if(e) {
            console.error('Ошибка БД: '+e.code);
            check_conn = false;
        }
    });
    connection.connect(function(e){
        if(e) console.error('Ошибка подключения к БД: '+e.code);
        else check_conn = true;
    });
}

function sql(sql,callback){
    if(!check_conn) conn_db();
    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
        if(err) console.error('Ошибка выполнения запроса к БД: '+err.code);
        callback(rows);
    });
}

sql('SELECT * FROM `users`',function(data){
    console.log('Data: ', data);
});
```

Тут тоже вроде бы всё хорошо ,но опять подомная проблема.
Что будет если два запроса будут почти одновременными?
Запрос на подключения пойдёт от первого запроса ,но второй не будет знать об этом так-как переменная всё ещё в false, так-как подключение занимает время и второй запрос тоже будет подключатся к БД, что тут произойдёт, лично я тоже не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю предполагается, что бот постоянно в памяти. Если коннект к базе только один, то просто держать соединение открытым. Перед выполнением очередной операции с БД выполнить какой нибудь простой запрос типа `select 123 from DUAL`. Если БД не вернет 123 - переустановить соединение. Специально держать открытым при отсутствии работы смысла не вижу.

Хотя конкретно MySQL не отличается долгим временем коннекта. практически все сайты на php открывают и рвут соединения при обращении за каждой страничкой сайта. И вроде ничего, справляются обычно.

Comment: Если открыть соединение и держать его открытым,примерно через 2мин бот падает вот с такой ошибкой:   http://joxi.ru/812MdlQHXbvemJ.jpg

Comment: Ну там написано 'не обработанная ошибка'. Значит надо ее обработать, например заключить запрос в `try {}` блок и на `catch`как раз переподключится. Я с nodejs конкретно не работал, но по аналогии с обычным JS должно быть как то так

Comment: Вы предлагаете делать так?  
При запуске бота подключатся к БД ,а при выполнение запросов проверять подключен ли он всё ещё к БД или уже отключился и отключился, заново подключатся и отправлять запрос?

Comment: Ну я бы скорее всего сделал подключение к БД в одном месте - когда работа с БД стала действительно нужной. При запуске может и не подключался бы сразу. У меня несколько сервисов работают по похожему принципу. но у меня БД на другом сервере и коннект может оборваться когда угодно из за проблем в сети. Кроме того у меня оракл который коннект пользователя выполняет гораздо дольше чем mysql